# Wildcard CSS code to hover code when a busy day is on the calendar

Tags: html, css, textbox, hover, element

I am currently using wordpress and Easy appointment plugin. I have calendar that shows red days for when it's busy and white when it's available. I would like to have text box pop up when it's busy. I have the code to show the text box here.

```
   display: block;
    content: "DAY IS NOT AVAILABLE";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    background: #f8f8f8;
    border-right: 5px solid #dfdfdf;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #dfdfdf;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 250px;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
```

However I don't know how to do it for the class that is the busy day? One example is "class="2022-06-28 busy". And each day changes. So I need to wildcard the date in the class. I have tried

```
[class^=”busy”]
{
    display: block;
    content: "DAY IS NOT AVAILABLE";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    background: #f8f8f8;
    border-right: 5px solid #dfdfdf;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #dfdfdf;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 250px;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

But that doesn't work. So basically I don't know how to wildcard for HTML elements in CSS code.

Comment: The quotes around `busy` are funny. Use regular quotation marks.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by the regular quotation marks. I see it looks like two right quote marks but I have tried both ways "", '' and highlighting the Busy comment and putting " on it and neither way worked

Answer (score 0):

Because there's a space between the date and "busy", you can simply target it with `.busy`.

```
.busy {
  display: block;
  content: "DAY IS NOT AVAILABLE";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  background: #f8f8f8;
  border-right: 5px solid #dfdfdf;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #dfdfdf;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 250px;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

Incidentally, `^=` means "starts with". For contains, you would use `[class~="busy"]`.

Comment: This messes up the red blocked calendar items and forces them to be diagonal red boxes.